# How to find mean pressure of 3 p.m (ds$Pressure3pm) for each wind direction of 3 p.m (WindDir3pm) in this dataset

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R programming, and I actually want to calculate mean pressure of 3 p.m (ds$Pressure3pm) for each wind direction of 3 p.m (WindDir3pm)

till now my code looks like :

```
ds <- read.csv("http://rattle.togaware.com/weather.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
str(ds)
```

to be honest, I do not fully understand how to do it in R and thus I required a bit of help.
 Thank you

Comment: Do you need `mean(df$WindDir3pm, na.rm = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Well i need to get the mean of WindDir3pm for each wind direction, and we get the wind direction from WindDir3pm

Comment: Oh i think i found it aggregate(ds$Pressure3pm ,by = list(ds$WindDir3pm) ,FUN = mean)

Comment: We don't have your data Shrey, because you didn't include it in your question. We have no idea what it looks like, what format it's in or whether it has NA values etc, so we can only really guess what you are trying to do here. If you have found something that works for you then that's great. If you aren't sure, please post a sample of your data along with your code so we can help you out. Thanks.